# incorrect values for a Commodity Channel Index Indicator

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I'm trying to make a simple CCI indicator but the values are incorrect (see photo).
I don't understand why. Can someone help me?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTAc5.png)

```
CCI= (.015×Mean Deviation) / (Typical Price−MA)

This is the script I wrote :
indicator('Commodity Channel Index', shorttitle='CCI', overlay=false)
length = input.int(24, minval=1)

// Typical Price (Mt)
mt = (high + low + close) / 3

// Simple Moving Average (SMt)
smt = ta.sma(mt, length) / 24

// Mean Deviation (md)
typ = (high + low + close) / 3
md = 0.0
for i = 1 to length - 1 by 1
md += math.abs(typ\[i\])
md
md /= length

// CCI (Commodity Channel Index)
cci = (mt - smt) / (0.015 \* md)
plot(cci, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='CCI', linewidth=1)
```

I was trying to build a CCI indicator

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own CCI indicator with just one line of code

[ta.cci](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcci)